# Does this give me a good baseline for categorical classification?

Tags: python, keras, categorical-data

I was reading up that for categorical classification you can basically just use the % of outputs that is your most popular category as your baseline. It makes sense because your model will probably just default to just guessing the most popular category every time. Given that this is true, does the code below accomplish what it should?

```
# get the index of the most popular category in your training outputs
pop_train_cat_ind = np.argmax(np.sum(train_Y, axis=0))

# get the count of that same category in your validation ouputs
pop_val_cat_ct = np.sum(validation_Y, axis=0)[pop_train_cat_ind]

# get the percentage compared to your total validation samples
baseline = pop_val_cat_ct / len(validation_Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the most frequent value from a list or an array, you can use the `mode` function from `scipy.stats`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode
train_Y=[1,7,3,4,6,4]
pop_train_cat_ind=mode(train_Y).mode[0]
print(pop_train_cat_ind)
```

The argmax function you used is not what you wanted to do because it doesn't get the most frequent value but the indices where `train_Y` has the maximal value (with `train_Y=[1,7,3,4,6,4]` it would return 1)

When you compute `pop_val_cat_ct`, you sum first all element in `validation_Y`, which returns a single number, and then you try to get the `pop_val_cat_ct`th element, which in general doesn't exist.

To compute properly `pop_val_cat_ct`, you should count the number of times where `validation_Y` is equal to `pop_train_cat_ind` and sum :

```
validation_Y=[1,8,4]
# get the count of that same category in your validation ouputs
pop_val_cat_ct = np.sum(validation_Y==pop_train_cat_ind)
```

`validation_Y==pop_train_cat_ind` gives an array of same length as `validation_Y` filled with True or False. When you sum it it returns the number of True values (for Python True=1 and False=0), so the count you need.

You can then do as you wrote

```
# get the percentage compared to your total validation samples
baseline = pop_val_cat_ct / len(validation_Y)
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain it better, I also noticed that the argmax part didn't work either so I added the first part